# Switching out old broken shaver socket for new one. Having trouble working out how to unwire the existing socket

Tags: electrical, bathroom, socket

I'm trying to work out how to unwire an existing shaver socket.
There are no obvious fasteners to loosen, just these weird red tabs that click backwards and forwards and can be pulled out entirely. Trying these options though doesn't seem to make any difference to the cables, which I'm unable to remove. 
[image: existing socket]

It's pretty hard to Google for this issue.
FYI, I'm in the United Kingdom.
Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: cut the cables off at the plug

Comment: What happens if you push the red tabs in?

Comment: Try twisting and pulling at the same time. And you might help by identifying your region. (Electrical is variable around the world.)

Comment: @bib they don't appear to be able to be pushed in, tried pushing hard with a Flathead screwdriver and I've had no luck.

Comment: It looks like the tabs are mounted on a pivot.  Try moving the "handle" up or down.

Comment: Looks like push-to-release connectors. So try pushing and removing the wire at same time.... at worst you can cut the wires as next as you can to the box and rewire the new outlet.

Comment: Turns out they were push to release connectors. Thanks for the assistance guys.

Answer (score 3):

For over a year, this "unanswered" question has had an answer and acceptance in the comments:

> Looks like push-to-release connectors. So try pushing and removing the
> wire at same time.... at worst you can cut the wires as next as you
> can to the box and rewire the new outlet. – DDS May 19 '18 at 9:22
>
> Turns out they were push to release connectors. Thanks for the
> assistance guys. – Iain May 19 '18 at 13:08